# How to hold a python list containing millions of dictionaries in RAM at once?

Tags: python, dictionary, large-data

I am storing huge csv file as list of dictionaries like below:

```
dictlist=[{ 'col-1' : 'data-1','col-2' : 'data-2','col-3' : 'data-3'},
           { 'col-1' : 'data-1','col-2' : 'data-2','col-3' : 'data-3'}]
```

where keys 1 and 2 are row numbers and value is data in csv file.

My problem is I need to convert csv file having like 4 million+ rows. But for that huge amount of data my data structure is not able to fit in the memory (RAM).

can someone help me to find a solution like storing the data structure to disk or something. I need to use the entire data structure at a time.

Thanks in advance

Comment: That is not valid syntax. Either use a list `[{...}, {...}]` or a dict `{1: {...}, 2: {...}}`.

Comment: you could split up your file and try using something like dask to read and process the data in blocks.

Comment: Thank you I got solved this problem by using disklist library.

Comment: @p.durgashankar You can add a snippet of code that helped you solve the problem for anyone who faces the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- I have solved this by using disklist library.
- First you need to install disklist library using pip (pip install disklist)
- After that you should import disklist and use it like list (some_variable_name = disklist())
- The disklist is almost same as list in python. But it will be stored in disk space rather than RAM.